# Retrieving items from users folder using Outlook Interop

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

I'm trying to retrieve emails from Outlook using Outlook Interop.

The following call works for Inbox and gets me items from Ibox folder

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder myInbox = mapiNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
```

But i also have folders which were created by the user, which i would like to retrieve, how can i get those folders?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oy2D.png)

Comment: Please read [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Also your title was very misleading. Everyone new to SO should have a read through the [help]. Specifically [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) *If you're having trouble summarizing the problem, write the title last - sometimes writing the rest of the question first can make it easier to describe the problem.*

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to use other value of your enumeration ? `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders`
[OlDefaultFolders Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff861868.aspx)

See this links for an Exmple of code : [How To: Get any standard / default folder in Outlook](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/05/how-to-get-any-standard-default-folder-in-outlook/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Namespace.GetDefaultFolder`, retrieve the store in question from the `Namespace.Stores` collection, then call `Store.GetDefaultFolder`.